# How to hide data that loads in the background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm currently working on a mobile application in AngularJS under the Ionic Framework, and was wondering how to hide a user from loading some of my pages? Not only at the level of the lists, but on pages containing details of a product, or product sheet for example. :)

I know that the loading system (ionicLoading) can be used until the data is loaded, but when it is too much it is not very clean.

If you have suggestions or tricks, other than the loading, I am grabbing :)

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by "hide a user from loading"? Can you clarify that? You want them to not see the images? or you want them not to load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My usual trick is to set a `$scope` variable to `false`, and then set it to `true` whenever whatever I'm waiting on is done. Usually, it's inside a promise, but for the sake of demo, we'll use `$timeout`.

With a `boolean` variable, we can then use Angular's built-in `ng-hide` and `ng-show` directives to control what DOM elements to hide/show based on our logic.

In the example here, `$scope.loaded` is `false` until our job is done (here, simply simulated with a 5 second `$timeout`)

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  
  $scope.loaded = false;
  
  //Simulate loading

  $timeout(function(){
     $scope.loaded = true;
  }, 5000);
 
  
});
```

```css
.container {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  background: #eee;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 800px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Verdana;
  padding: 20px 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <div class="container">
    <div ng-hide="loaded">
      <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
      <p>Loading...</p>
    </div>

    <div ng-show="loaded">
      <i class="fa fa-check fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
      <p>All done.</p>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Plunker mirror here: http://plnkr.co/edit/zEmdKQ3QBCpqORsb6RdT?p=preview

Comment: Better will be to use directly `$timeout` instead of `window.setTimeout`, you wouldn't need `$scope.$apply();`. `$scope.$apply();` isn't recommanded at all

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of `ionicLoading` is really easy to understand.

All the logic is allowed in your controller:

```
$ionicLoading.show({
  template: 'Loading Data...', // The html content of the indicator
  duration: 3000 // How many milliseconds to wait until automatically hiding the indicator
});
```

You need to put that before of making your request to your backend service or endpoint. When the request is finished, you only need to hide the overlay using the following method:

```
$ionicLoading.hide().then(function(){
  console.log("The loading indicator is now hidden");
});
```

On the [official docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/service/$ionicLoading/), you can find more information about use this.